# Android studio for flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was currently using android studio for developing android apps and now I want to work with flutter in the already installed android studio. How can I switch from android to flutter? Do I have to uninstall and reinstall android studio to work with flutter?

Comment: You can refer to fluter documentation for the setup guide

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/editor

Answer (score 1):

1. download flutter sdk
2. set flutter environment path
3. on Android Studio, install flutter plugin, and dart plugin
4. run command `flutter doctor` to make sure your flutter environment work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install flutter and dart sdk from official website and set the path.
In android studio you have to install two plugins first is Flutter and second is dart.
(Open plugin preferences (File > Settings > Plugins).
Select Marketplace, select the Flutter plugin and click Install.)
once you have installed both plugins restart your android studio.